# spring data jpa with native query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying spring data JPA. My repository method is like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM test_result WHERE FK_TEST_PAPER_ID=?1 AND PERCENTAGE_OBTAINED BETWEEN :?2 AND :?3 ?#{#pageable}", nativeQuery = true)
Page<TestResult> findResult(long testPaperId, Float minpercentage, Float maxpercentage, Pageable pageInfo);
```

My service implementation code is like this:

```
Page<TestResult> getAllResult1 = testResultRepository.findResult(testPaperId,minpercentage,maxpercentage,pageInfo);
```

And I am getting this error : `Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter!`
I am new to spring. Please help.

Comment: Did you check answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `?#{#pageable}` from query